# Tensorflow Object Detection API Evaluation mAP randomly goes to 0

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, object-detection-api

I am using the Tensorflow Object Detection API to train a SSDLite (MobileNet V2) object detection model. During the course of training, the evaluation results spontaneously go to 0 at unpredictable parts of the training (in pic below after ~35k iterations). Notably, the training loss is not affected, which makes me think this is not just an exploding gradient problem.

**EDIT**: The issue only seems to happen when I use larger input image resolution, in this case 640x480. If I keep the original 300x300 input resolution, everything works correctly.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/rsandler00/855f6ec134d0a244af0ad2c5eed59e70) is a link to my config file in case that helps.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I remember having this problem as well. And the reason was the data. Try to re-create the tfrecords, inspect them by fetching images and boxes and printing them. Prior to that, you may try to reduce learning rate, it can be helpful sometimes. BTW, what is the number of samples in your training set?

Comment: @DmytroPrylipko see my comment. Seems to be problem w/ higher input resolution.